# Unable to fetch Debian packages with remote repository on Artifactory

Tags: ubuntu, artifactory, apt

I’ve added this remote repository to Artifactory: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian. The test button says everything is ok, but when I do `apt-get update` I get this:

```
Err:3 https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote binary/ Packages
404  Not Found
Ign:4 https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote binary/ Translation-en_US
Ign:5 https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote binary/ Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote binary/Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote/binary/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

What I am doing wrong?

Here is traced request:

```
curl 'https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages?trace'
Request ID: d23de3b6
Repo Path ID: jenkins-remote:dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
Method Name: GET
User: reader
Time: 2017-08-29T05:48:35.074Z
Thread: http-nio-8081-exec-2975
Steps:
2017-08-29T05:48:35.074Z Received request
2017-08-29T05:48:35.074Z Request source = 87.2.89.127, Last modified = 31-12-69 23:59:59 +00:00, If modified since = -1, Thread name = http-nio-8081-exec-2975
2017-08-29T05:48:35.074Z Executing any BeforeDownloadRequest user plugins that may exist
2017-08-29T05:48:35.074Z Retrieving info from {} repository '{}' type
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Requested resource is found = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Request is HEAD = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Request is for a checksum = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Target repository is not remote or doesn't store locally = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Requested resource was not modified = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Responding with unfound resource
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Setting default response status to '404' reason to 'Resource not found'
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Response is an instance of UnfoundRepoResourceReason
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Configured to hide un-authorized resources = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Original response status is auth related = false
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Using original response status of '404' and message 'Not Found'
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Sending error with status 404 and message 'Not Found'
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Executing any AfterDownloadErrorAction user plugins that may exist
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Response code wasn't modified by the user plugins
2017-08-29T05:48:35.075Z Sending response with the status '404' and the message 'Not Found'
```

Here’s the diff between `debian-remote` (works OK) and `jenkins-remote`:

```
> diff debian-remote jenkins-remote
2c2
<   "key" : "debian-remote",
---
>   "key" : "jenkins-remote",
4c4
<   "description" : "Mirror of Ubuntu archive repo (local file cache)",
---
>   "description" : "Mirror of Jenkins (local file cache)",
26c26
<   "url" : "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/",
---
>   "url" : "https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian",
57a58
>   "mismatchingMimeTypesOverrideList" : "",
```

Comment: try running [a trace query](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval) (adding `?trace` to the end of the URL) and see what it prints?

Comment: @JBaruch I’ve edited the original post with the tracing you asked for. Hope I understood your request correctly. Let me know and thanks for you help.

Comment: @JBaruch Also what `W: The repository 'https://onebip.jfrog.io/onebip/jenkins-remote xenial Release' does not have a Release file.` does it mean?

Comment: Well the tracing is clear – `Target repository is not remote`. Are you sure `jenkins-remote` is actually remote?

Comment: @JBaruch I’ve addede the diff between `debian-remote` (that works) and `jenkins-remote`, seem pretty similar to me.